# Process.Start Argument Problem --- Escaping an "=" character?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start().  For example:

```
string target = @"c:\te=mp\test";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", target)
```

The target variable is actually supplied more dynamically and does on occasion include an "=" sign which is a legal character in filenames and directories.

The issue is that this triggers an error indicating, "The Path '**mp\test**' does not exist or is not a directory."  It seems that the path argument is cutoff to the left of the "=" character.

Is there a way to escape the "=" characteror otherwise work-around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try wrapping it in quotes, e.g.

```
string target = @"""c:\te=mp\test""";
```

Comment: So this accomplished the goal.  Can you tell me why, exactly?

Comment: sometimes, the arguments passed to a process via the command line are parsed for structure, e.g. a=b may be interpreted as 'the a parameter has a value of b'. by wrapping the argument in quotes, you are explicitly stating that the value is to be used as a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the offending parameter. For example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "\"" + target + "\"");
```

Comment: @JR - The code appends a quote to the beginning and end of the target parameter. The quotes are escaped using blackslashes. `"\"" == @""""`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use double quotes:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe",  @"""c:\te=mp\test""");
```